# Debugging seg fault on Heroku with native gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I've written native ruby gems before and run them on Heroku with good results.  But this one has me stumped.

All tests - aggressive ones - run fine under both Mac OS X (Mavericks) and Linux (though the only installation I have access to is Redhat).   On Heroku the same gem seg faults on live data that are smaller and simpler than the tests.  The gem also runs fine in my OS X Rails development environment with a copy of the live data pulled down from Heroku.

The stack trace from the Heroku logs is not helpful.  The Ruby-level trace shows the offending call. Great. But then the C call stack is weird.  It has the top level gem API call with a line number that doesn't make any sense.  Deeper stack frames name files from my gems and seem roughly possible, but the line numbers point to straight-line code and blank space, not call sites.  It looks like the debug information mapping is somewhat off.

Another problem is that even though the file names are from my gem, the referenced `.so` file is wrong (`zlib` in fact).

The general form of the stack trace seemed to point to memory allocation or deallocation or bogus pointer reference bug, so I followed [these instructions](http://blog.flavorjon.es/2009/06/easily-valgrind-gdb-your-ruby-c.html) to run the gem under `valgrind`.  It comes up completely clean.

Not sure where to go from here.  Questions that seem reasonable to me, but YMMV:

1. Is there a way to get the Heroku stack trace to make sense?
2. Are there suggestions to force the error in a dev environment?
3. Any other suggestions?

Here is the relevant part of the Heroku trace.  I can Gist the whole thing if anyone thinks it's relevant.

```
2014-05-05T01:20:29.366714+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby(rb_bug+0xb3) [0x573153] error.c:277
2014-05-05T01:20:29.366720+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby() [0x4b5f50] signal.c:644
2014-05-05T01:20:29.366722+00:00 app[web.1]: /lib/libpthread.so.0(+0xf8f0) [0x7f99ace9f8f0]
2014-05-05T01:20:29.366724+00:00 app[web.1]: /lib/libz.so.1(adler32+0x288) [0x7f99ab0325b8]
2014-05-05T01:20:29.366726+00:00 app[web.1]: /lib/libz.so.1(+0x4f8d) [0x7f99ab034f8d] qt.c:58
2014-05-05T01:20:29.366728+00:00 app[web.1]: /lib/libz.so.1(+0x699d) [0x7f99ab03699d] lulu.c:208
2014-05-05T01:20:29.366730+00:00 app[web.1]: /lib/libz.so.1(deflate+0x151) [0x7f99ab035281] qt.c:24
2014-05-05T01:20:29.366732+00:00 app[web.1]: /lib/libz.so.1(compress2+0xa6) [0x7f99ab032986] marker.c:76
2014-05-05T01:20:29.366734+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/lulu-0.0.2/lib/lulu/lulu.so(+0x6e82) [0x7f99a6ddce82] lulu.c:223
2014-05-05T01:20:29.369302+00:00 app[web.1]:   428 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.14/lib/sass/selector/abstract_sequence.rb
```

My gem is named `lulu`.  The bottom entry is the initial call and higher frames end at `signal.c` where the error is raised.  `marker.c` and `qt.c` are my files, but they are defined in `lulu.so`, not `zlib`.

[Here is source code](http://rubygems.org/gems/lulu), though I don't expect anyone to do a code review...  I'm calling all the `ruby` `malloc` routines like a good ruby citizen. It's ruby 1.9.3, incidentally.

**Addition**

Maybe I have a clue.  The reference `lulu.c:223` is a call to my own function `compress`.  There is a `compress` in `zlib`, too.  My guess is that the dynamic loader is getting the wrong one.  Wait out while I try renaming `compress`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did turn out that the loader was finding `compress` in `zlib` instead of the same-named function in my code.

The call and definition are in the same C file!  I did not realize Linux would dynamically link a function and its uses within the same object file and prefer a previously loaded function of the same name!

I fixed the problem by declaring my `compress` to be static.